# Nesting a span with an icon within a span in Angular

Tags: html, angular

I am working on changing the function of an add button into an icon that is added and shown to each list item based on *ngIf statement. For some reason what i currently have displays the add icon to all items of the list and doesn't seem to be considering the if statement at all and i am not sure what i am doing wrong.

This is my original working button:

```
<button *ngIf="selectedItemIndex === -1" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="emptyRequiredValue() || isSelectedNameValid(selecteditem.name) === false" (click)="onAddNew()>
   Add
</button>
```

I have converted this into a span which shows an icon next to each list item.

```
<li *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index">
   <span (click)="onSelectedItemClicked(i)">
        {{item.name}}
   </span>
   <span (click)="onAddNew()" *ngIf="selectedItemIndex === -1" class="win-icon win-icon-add"></span>
</li>
```

The behavior that is happening is that once i click on a list item then the add icon appears for all the items in the list which some should've not passed the if statement within the second span.

How can i adjust this so once an item has been selected from the list that it will display the add icon for that specific project.

Comment: Share the associate .ts file

Comment: @bluePearl: You want to hide span, if selectedItemIndex === -1?

Comment: I'am not pretty sure you want achieve. But I think that you want is *ngIf="selectedItemIndex ===i" (the win-icon-class appear once you click the item.name)